# ¿Como desplegar un dropdown multinivel con Vue y Bootstrap 3.3.7?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap, vue.js

El código para el dropdown multinivel ya esta completo, el problema está al quererlo llenar por medio de `v-for` con Vue, un detalle importante podría estar al no encontrar una etiqueta que contenga a las etiquetas `<a></a>` y `<ul></ul>`, lo que busco es desplegar ese multinivel de la forma `v-for="departamento in departamentos"` a continuación muestro el código del componente Vue:

```
<template>
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button">Departamentos <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li v-for="departamento in departamentos" class="dropdown-submenu">
                <a class="desplegar" tabindex="-1" href="#">1er nivel <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">2do nivel</a></li>
                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">2do nivel</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data: function() {
            return {
                departamentos:[],
            }
        },
        mounted: function() {
            this.show()
        },
        methods: {
            show: function() {
                let self = this
                axios.get('/departamentos').then(function(response){
                    self.departamentos = response.data
                })
            },
        }
    };
```

Uso de JQuery para desplegar el multinivel:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.dropdown-submenu a.desplegar').on("click", function(e){
            $(this).next('ul').toggle();
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Código para agregar el estilo al multinivel:

```
<style>
    .dropdown-submenu {
        position: relative;
    }

    .dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
        top: 0;
        left: 100%;
        margin-top: -1px;
    }
</style>
```

Ejemplo del resultado **sin** la etiqueta `v-for="departamento in departamentos"`:
[image: Ejemplo del resultado sin la etiqueta <code>v-for="departamento in departamentos"</code>]

Cuando se agrega `v-for="departamento in departamentos"` se muestra el primer nivel y al dar clic el dropdown se oculta...

Todo el código mostrado en bloques pertenece al mismo archivo. De antemano gracias...

Comment: Vos lo que queres es que se abra automaticamente el dropdown? si no es asi, podrias mostrar un ejemplo mas claro. Y aparte de eso, sabias que hay un componente bootstrap-vue que te ahorra todo ese trabajo manual?

Comment: Ya fue actualizada la pregunta agregando el resultado al final, para más detalles de lo que se quiere lograr. El proyecto ya esta construido con webpack de laravel, usando bootstrap y vue de la forma tradicional no puedo cambiar el modelo de trabajo utilizando bootstrap-vue, aún así gracias por tu comentario.

Comment: Quieres algo así: https://jsfiddle.net/v5aj9kbL/2/ ?

Comment: Es correcto bro, el problema ya fue resuelto, me dejas buena referencia, gracias por contribuir...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Les dejo la forma en que resolví el problema y algunos puntos a considerar en este tipo de proyectos:

1. Tratar de evitar utilizar JQuery desde Vue.
2. Resolver este tipo de problemas con stilos de complemento a Bootstrap.

El template queda de la forma:

```
<template>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Departamentos <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level">
            <li v-for="departamento in departamentos" class="dropdown-submenu">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">{{departamento.nombre}}</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Action 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Action 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Action 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</template>
```

Y el nuevo estilo que complementa a bootstrap queda de la siguiente manera:

```
<style>
    .dropdown-submenu {
        position: relative;
    }

    .dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu {
        top: 0;
        left: 100%;
        margin-top: -6px;
        margin-left: -1px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
        -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 6px;
        border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
    }

    .dropdown-submenu:hover>.dropdown-menu {
        display: block;
    }

    .dropdown-submenu>a:after {
        display: block;
        content: " ";
        float: right;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-color: transparent;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
        border-left-color: #ccc;
        margin-top: 5px;
        margin-right: -10px;
    }

    .dropdown-submenu:hover>a:after {
        border-left-color: #fff;
    }

    .dropdown-submenu.pull-left {
        float: none;
    }

    .dropdown-submenu.pull-left>.dropdown-menu {
        left: -100%;
        margin-left: 10px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
        -moz-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
        border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
    }
</style>
```

> El código se obtuvo de la fuente a continuación: [gracias la contribución de Ajay Patel en Codepen.](https://codepen.io/ajaypatelaj/pen/prHjD)